# How do I link to libraries when compiling a win32 project with gcc?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gcc

I am trying to compile a basic hello word winform application with gcc on Win 7.

The code is this:

```
/*

  WINHELLO.C

  "Hello, world!", Win32 style.

*/

#include <windows.h>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);


/*  WinMain(), our entry point  */

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
           LPSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow) {
    static char szAppName[] = "winhello";
    HWND        hwnd;
    MSG         msg;
    WNDCLASSEX  wndclass;


    /*  Fill in WNDCLASSEX struct members  */

    wndclass.cbSize         = sizeof(wndclass);
    wndclass.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon          = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszClassName  = szAppName;
    wndclass.lpszMenuName   = NULL;


    /*  Register a new window class with Windows  */

    RegisterClassEx(&wndclass);


    /*  Create a window based on our new class  */

    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName, "Hello, world!",
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
            NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);


    /*  Show and update our window  */

    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);


    /*  Retrieve and process messages until we get WM_QUIT  */

    while ( GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) ) {
    TranslateMessage(&msg);    /*  for certain keyboard messages  */
    DispatchMessage(&msg);     /*  send message to WndProc        */
    } 


    /*  Exit with status specified in WM_QUIT message  */

    return msg.wParam;
}


/*  Window procedure  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT iMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC         hdc;


    /*  Switch according to what type of message we have received  */

    switch ( iMsg ) {
    case WM_PAINT:

    /*  We receive WM_PAINT every time window is updated  */

    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    TextOut(hdc, 100, 100, "Hello, world!", 13);
    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:

    /*  Window has been destroyed, so exit cleanly  */

    PostQuitMessage(0);
    return 0;
    }


    /*  Send any messages we don't handle to default window procedure  */

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, iMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The command I give to the compiler is `gcc C:\Users\Bobby\Desktop\myfile.c`

Well, it looks for libraries:

```
C:\Users\Bobby\desktop>gcc C:\Users\Bobby\Desktop\myfile.c
C:\Users\Bobby\AppData\Local\Temp\ccT0bq97.o:myfile.c:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'
C:\Users\Bobby\AppData\Local\Temp\ccT0bq97.o:myfile.c:(.text+0x1db): undefined reference to `TextOutA@20'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
PS C:\Users\Scruffy\desktop> .\build.bat

C:\Users\Bobby\desktop>gcc C:\Users\Bobby\Desktop\myfile.c -I Gdi32.lib
C:\Users\Bobby\AppData\Local\Temp\ccylV5js.o:myfile.c:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `GetStockObject@4'
C:\Users\Bobby\AppData\Local\Temp\ccylV5js.o:myfile.c:(.text+0x1db): undefined reference to `TextOutA@20'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
PS C:\Users\Bobby\desktop> C:\MinGW\
```

I did some googling and well I found out that this first `GetStockObject@4` is in a file called Gdi32.lib . So i searched my harddrive and through MinGW and could not locate it. Where is the Lib to locate this function and what is the way to link to it? Also I think I must link to `TextOutA@20`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of linking against GDI32 explicitly, you should use the `-mwindows` subsystem option in this case:

```
gcc -Wall -mwindows winhello.c -o winhello.exe
```

Note:

gcc et al. prefer .a files over .lib, so you should've been looking for `libgdi32.a`. You can still link against either by giving the filename as a parameter:

```
gcc src.c /path/to/example1.lib /path/to/libexample2.a
```

or using the `-l` option for .a files:

```
gcc src.c /path/to/example1.lib -L/path/to -lexample2
```

Comment: Thanks. Where did gcc find those functions?

Comment: The documentation didn't help much in this case, unfortunately. It's common knowledge in Windows development that you can have subsystem-console and -windows applications. Most people learn about it when they search for "how to get rid of this console window in my Win32 application" for the first time nowadays, I believe. I can't think of any other obscure pieces of extremely useful information. Well, maybe keep `-DUNICODE` and `-D_UNICODE` in mind if you're having char-type-related issues.

Answer (score 0):

Windows DLL needs so-called *import library* for the linker to resolve references to its exported functions. Microsoft supplies import librarirs, including **Gdi32.lib**, with Windows SDK. This file should not be deployed to end users.